# How to override Clone() on a WinForms DataGridViewCell?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clone

I am creating a `DataGridViewCalendarCell` based on [this MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) and I want to override the Clone of the base class `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` because I have added two properties to `DataGridViewCalendarCell`. The problem is that I'm not sure of how to go about this.

### Why I think I need to override Clone:

The `DateTimePicker` has two properties: `CustomFormat` and `Format` that I want to expose on through properties on my `CalendarColumn` Class that I can set when initializing the `CalendarColumn`. These properties will then set the properties on the `DataGridViewCalendarCell` that the column uses as a template like so:

```
public string CustomFormat { 
    get {
        return ((DataGridViewCalendarCell)base.CellTemplate).CustomFormat;
    }
    set {
        ((DataGridViewCalendarCell)base.CellTemplate).CustomFormat = value;
    }
}

public DateTimePickerFormat Format {
    get {
        return ((DataGridViewCalendarCell)base.CellTemplate).Format;
    }
    set {
        ((DataGridViewCalendarCell)base.CellTemplate).Format = value;
    }
}
```

In the `DataGridViewCalendarCell.InitializeEditingControl` function the properties are again passed on to the `DateTimePicker` used to edit the cell value.

The problem I have is that when `DataGridViewCalendarCell.InitializeEditingControl` is called the `Format` and `CustomFormat` are not set anymore.

I am guessing this is because the actual `DataGridViewCalendarCell`s are clones of the template. As I didn't override the `Clone` method of `DateGridViewTextBoxCell`, my extra properties are not cloned as well.

Also, there is a nice note in the MSDN article:

> When you derive from DataGridViewCell or DataGridViewColumn and add
>   new properties to the derived class, be sure to override the Clone
>   method to copy the new properties during cloning operations. You
>   should also call the base class's Clone method so that the properties
>   of the base class are copied to the new cell or column.

### Why I don't know how to override Clone:

This makes me feel like there is a standard way to do this for WinForms controls, but I can't find anything about it.

There is no copy constructor on `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` to which I can pass the clone returned from `base.Clone()`. I prefer not to use Reflection because I'm not sure how to tell which properties I should and shouldn't copy. I wonder if I could do something with serialization, but I am afraid of any side effects that I can't oversee, right now.

Is there a standard way to override Clone on a custom control?

EDIT: I editted the question title because the cloning is not relevant for all custom controls, just for `DataGridViewCell`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573594/210336) to another question about cloning.

> The other approach is to use Object.MemberwiseClone in the implementation of Clone - this will ensure that result is always of the correct type, and will allow overrides to extend

Apparently `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` is using `Object.MemberwiseClone` because I was able to cast the result of `base.Clone()` to `DataGridViewCalendarCell`.

Here is my implementation of `Clone()` that did the trick:

```
class DataGridViewCalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    (...)

    public string CustomFormat { get; set; }
    public DateTimePickerFormat Format { get; set; }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        var clone = (DataGridViewCalendarCell)base.Clone();

        clone.Format = Format;
        clone.CustomFormat = CustomFormat;

        return clone;
    }
}
```